# Why does Easy Stroke work when logged out?

Tags: startup-applications, gestures

I have created a gesture in Easy Stroke for my password to unlock keyring and to install new packages. However, recently while logging in, I tried the gesture and it worked.

It is not a big problem for me but shouldn't it  be disabled while the logging in for security reasons? Is there a way to fix this?